# oracle force partition pruning with in condition

Tags: sql, oracle, partitioning, pruning

I have a table with list partitions on two columns in order of MY_ID (integer with values 1,2,3,5,8...1100), RUN_DATE (past some days).

My query is

```
select * from my_partitioned_table 
where run_date = '10-sep-2014' 
and my_id in (select my_id from mapping_table where category = 1)
;
```

It is going for full table scan, with following explain plan.

```
PX RECEIVE      115K    4M  600     1,01    PCWP            
PX SEND BROADCAST   :TQ10000    115K    4M  600     1,00    P->P    BROADCAST       
PX BLOCK ITERATOR       115K    4M  600     1,00    PCWC            
TABLE ACCESS FULL   MAPPING_TABLE   115K    4M  600     1,00    PCWP    
PX BLOCK ITERATOR       1G  412G    34849   1,01    PCWC        1   16
TABLE ACCESS FULL   MY_PARTITIONED_TABLE    1G  412G    34849   1,01    PCWP        KEY     KEY
```

How can I force it to access only certain partitions rather than going for full table scan?

Sorry I am little new to Oracle hints and couldn't find specific question before.

Comment: Show us the table's structure, please

Answer (score 2):

That query plan indicates that it is going after one (or more) partitions of `my_partitioned_table`.  So partition pruning is happening already.

You've cut off the column headers when you posted your explain plan (it would also be helpful to get a fixed width version).  But the last two columns are almost assuredly the start and end partitions.  When you see `KEY` for a start or an end partition, that means that Oracle is determining the set of partitions that it actually needs to scan at runtime.  In this case, it needs to determine the set of `my_id` values that your subquery will return before it can determine which partitions from your table need to be accessed.  The `TABLE ACCESS FULL` bit merely indicates that it is going to do a full scan of the partition(s) that it needs to access.

Comment: Is it possible to know exactly which partitions were actually scanned after the execution of the query? Thanks for quick answer.

Comment: @androboy - I'm not aware of a way to get that information off the top of my head though you could almost certainly deduce it from a trace file if you traced an execution.  Depending on your environment, you could also make some deductions by watching the number of reads that your session is doing and the number of reads that have been done to the various segments.